# How to refresh spinner from main activity after inserted to sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, refresh, spinner

I working on an aplication that uses rest to get data from mysql to sqlite database. On main activity, I have a spinner and after I synchronize data by pressing seckronize button, data inserted to sqlite but after that when I query data It can not catch result and returns empty cursor. Since cursor requery depracated which method should I use. Maybe loaders but when I try loaders I do not know how to trigger loaders if there is an update in database. I do not want to use content providers.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://codetheory.in/asynchronous-background-execution-and-data-loading-with-loaders-framework-in-android/) out .Its a good tutorial on how to load in background with several useful callback methods